# Firebase architecture

Tags: django, angular, firebase

I currently have a server running in Django and a frontend in Angular 2. I'm planning to build a chat messaging using Firebase but I don't know if I should call the saving of data directly in client or send it first in my server and do the calls there.

1) Client sends a message -> Firebase
If I structure it like this, any users can have a read and write access on the database

2) Client sends a message -> My Server (Using a service account) -> Firebase
And if I structure it like this, clients will only have a read access so they can only subscribe but not send any message.

What's the ideal way of doing it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Firebase is meant for the Client sends a message -> Firebase Architecture.

It is your responsibility to setup Rules correctly in Firebase so that read and write access on the database is based upon their Role/Authentication etc.

you may read more about configuring rules at [Firebase : Security & Rules Quickstart](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/quickstart.html)